# Refresh UIImageView's Image

Tags: ios, swift, image

I have a question that has probably been asked a lot, but I just can't get it. I'm making an iOS tabbed app with Swift 5 and Xcode 11. I have a background UIImageView that changes the image every time a user presses a button. The image actually displays pretty well, there's just one thing: The background image doesn't change, it just takes the previous image. Here's my code:

```swift
    func theme(){
        let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: self.view1.bounds)
        backgroundImage.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        self.view1.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
        if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "like") == 1{
            backgroundImage.image = nil
            backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "img1")
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.84, green:0.84, blue:0.84, alpha:1.0)
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.21, green:0.56, blue:0.96, alpha:1.0)
            ansView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            historyButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            for button in operatorButtons {
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            }
            for button in numberButtons {
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.53, green:0.52, blue:0.53, alpha:0.5)
            }
            equalButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.49, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.78, green:0.78, blue:0.78, alpha:1.0)
            view1.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        }else if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "like") == 2{
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.98, green:0.64, blue:0.02, alpha:1.0)
            backgroundImage.image = nil
            backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "img2")
            ansView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.53, green:0.52, blue:0.53, alpha:1)
            historyButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.9)
            for button in operatorButtons {
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.9)
            }
            for button in numberButtons {
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.53, green:0.52, blue:0.53, alpha:0.5)
            }
            equalButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.53, green:0.52, blue:0.53, alpha:0.5)
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            view1.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        }else if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "like") == 3{
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.78, green:0.75, blue:0.90, alpha:1.0)
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.51, green:0.44, blue:0.78, alpha:1.0)
            view1.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "ing3")!)
            ansView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:1.00, blue:1.00, alpha:0.5)
            historyButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.60, green:0.54, blue:0.82, alpha:1.0)
            for button in operatorButtons {
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.60, green:0.54, blue:0.82, alpha:1.0)
            }
            for button in numberButtons {
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:1.00, blue:1.00, alpha:0.5)
            }
            equalButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.51, green:0.44, blue:0.78, alpha:1.0)
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.78, green:0.75, blue:0.90, alpha:1.0)
            view1.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleToFill
        }
    }
```

The above code was my theme function, which I call every time the view appears.
As you see above, I have tried

```swift
backgroundImage.image = nil
```

But it didn't work for me. I have also searched stack-overflow for similar questions, but it was no use. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Not that you are not merely changing the image; you are adding a new image view every time. This will cause the images to pile up on one another and is probably not what you want.

Comment: @matt I only added 1 image at the beginning, then changed as I went. If im wrong, could you please clarify this for me?

Comment: Please show real code, fully, in context, if you want more help.

Comment: @KLM - First, there is no reason to set `.image = nil`. Second, is this your actual code? That is, are you creating `backgroundImage` and calling `self.view1.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)` every time you want to change the image?

Comment: @matt see my edits

Comment: @DonMag see my edits, now the above is my real code.

Comment: Did you debug? Is the right code being called?

Comment: @matt yes, I debugged it and ran it a few times. Everything works except when the background image changes.

Comment: @matt It's similar, but the answer doesn't seem to work. By the way, this is what I get in my debugger:"_BSMachError: port 6207; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND""

Comment: @KLM - so... you are calling `theme()` every time the user taps the button? If so, you are inserting a new `UIImageView` ***behind*** the existing `UIImageView`. You need to create and insert the image view ***once*** and then set its `.image` property on each following tap.

Comment: @DonMag which is basically what I said in my first comment :) Except that I should have said "under" instead of "on". :))))

Comment: @matt - yep... not sure if he understands that yet though :(

Answer (score 0):

In the third condition you forgot to set image or it's intentionally ? 
And there is no need to set nil before replacing the new image.